# Any way of doing unwrap_or_return to do an early return

Tags: rust, return, unwrap

Is there any way to simplify the returns in the following example (originally copied from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/early_returns.html)):

```
fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> i32 {
    let first_number = match first_number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(n) => n,
        Err(_) => return -1,
    };

    let second_number = match second_number_str.parse::<i32>() {
        Ok(n) => n,
        Err(_) => return -2,
    };

    first_number * second_number
}

fn main () {
    assert_eq!(2, multiply("1", "2"));
    assert_eq!(-1, multiply("a", "2"));
    assert_eq!(-2, multiply("1", "b"));
    assert_eq!(-1, multiply("a", "b"));
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fb57167cbefc8d51807bceb69d2e265)

I mean something like:

```
fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> i32 {
    let first_number = first_number_str.parse::<i32>().unwrap_or_return(-1);
    let second_number = second_number_str.parse::<i32>().unwrap_or_return(-2);

    first_number * second_number
}

fn main () {
    assert_eq!(2, multiply("1", "2"));
    assert_eq!(-1, multiply("a", "2"));
    assert_eq!(-2, multiply("1", "b"));
    assert_eq!(-1, multiply("a", "b"));
}
```

If there is no straight way, what're the best practices for it?

Answer (score 3):

It becomes easier if the return type is not `i32`, but `Result<i32, SomeErrorType>`.

In this case, you can use the question mark to get something like this:

```
fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> Result<i32, i32> {
    let first_number = first_number_str.parse::<i32>().map_err(|_| -1)?;
    let second_number = second_number_str.parse::<i32>().map_err(|_| -2)?;

    Ok(first_number * second_number)
}

fn main () {
    assert_eq!(Ok(2), multiply("1", "2"));
    assert_eq!(Err(-1), multiply("a", "2"));
    assert_eq!(Err(-2), multiply("1", "b"));
    assert_eq!(Err(-1), multiply("a", "b"));
}
```

If I were doing it, I'd probably go with this code. Needless to say, I would not use `Result<i32, i32>`, but instead `Result<i32, CustomErrorTypeDenotingIfProblemIsAOrB>`. Possibly I would even keep the error type of `parse`, by leaving out `map_err`.

[Here's](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html?highlight=result#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) information about the question mark operator.

If you insist on keeping a single `i32` as return value, [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) offers a lot of different methods that can help to acchieve something similar to your goal. However, I am not aware of a single, canonical way of doing this, so I would possibly have a look at `and_then`, `map_err` and others.

**Edit:** I just realized that this is actually suggested in [the next chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/result/enter_question_mark.html).

Comment: I don't like overusing Errors in `Result` to deliver the result. And the caller should always check for `Ok` and then `Err` which is not what people mostly do.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could rewrite it in functional style using Result::map_or:

```
fn multiply(first_number_str: &str, second_number_str: &str) -> i32 {
    first_number_str.parse::<i32>().map_or(-1, |first| { 
        second_number_str.parse::<i32>().map_or(-2, |second| first*second)
    })
}
```

Comment: Good one, but it can work if you have a small amount of logic and a small number of conditions.